# MySQL: join with special character in column name

Tags: mysql

I have column name with special character like "`TRUCK_#`". Two tables "`shipment`" and other is "`truck`". Both have this "`TRUCK_#`" column in common. I want to perform a join on column "`TRUCK_#`"

I have written this query

```
SELECT * FROM shipment RIGHT JOIN truck on shipment.TRUCK_#=truck.TRUCK_#
```

It gives me an error saying

```
Unknown column name 'shipment.TRUCK_' near ON
```

I think its not taking the special character. Can anyone tell me how to correct it. Thanx in advance.

Comment: try with ` TRUCK_# `, using these quotes: `` (ignore the white spaces, stackoverflow hides these quotes for decoration reasons)

Comment: tried that already with single and double quotes also, didn't  work

Comment: It's not really a single or a double quote, its a "shell quote". just copy paste that quote in the first comment. look at the differences: ` and ' , first being a shell quote and the second being a normal single quote.

Comment: Ya got it when you told, didn't see that clearly earlier...

Thanks a lot, it worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM shipment RIGHT JOIN truck on `shipment`.`TRUCK_#`=`truck`.`TRUCK_#`
```

Comment: this will also work smokie...

SELECT * FROM shipment RIGHT JOIN truck on shipment.`TRUCK_#`=truck.`TRUCK_#`

and thanx again....

Comment: hey smokie, can you tell me what difference this shell quote makes compared to normal quotes

Comment: @user3454819, these are two different ASCII characters, please look them up online. Unix quotes are used in unix terminals in order to execute an inline command. in MySQL, a single quote acts the same as a double quote, to wrap a string. and a unix quote to wrap tables, columns, stored procedures etc..